# Checking if attribute field for labeling is present to avoid ArcMap Drawing Errors?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.1

I have a project with several layers in the TOC that point to feature classes or shapefiles. Each of them is using labels and everything is ok.
If I replace the source of these layers with some other feature classes/shapefiles with different attribute fields, sometimes it happens that the atribute field for labeling is in the new source data missing. That means that in the layer properties the *Label features in this layer* checkbox is ticked but the window with the attribute field is blank. Then when refreshing the layout view, the ArcMap *sometimes* (I don´t know why only sometimes but still) throws an error window like this:

[image: The error window that sometimes pops up]

Since I can´t rely on ArcMap because the error window sometimes pops up and sometimes not, is there a way to use arcpy for looping through all layers in the TOC and find those with broken labels (=missing attribute field for labeling)? I can´t find anything about this possibility and no one has asked similar question.

Comment: Maybe this can be done by listing layer fields and compare this to the fields used in the labels by using LabelClass. I have not tried it though. http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/labelclass-class.htm

Comment: I will try and parse the "expression" property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're working with layer (*lyr) file so you have an access to it's properties: `lyr.labelClasses` ([arcpy.mapping.Layer](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/layer-class.htm)).

`.labelClasses` returns a list of label definitions. Get the first: `layer.labelClasses[0]`, this will be an instance of *LabelClass*.

LabelClass has only a few properties. The one you need is `labelClass.expression` ([arcpy.mapping.LabelClass](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/labelclass-class.htm)). It will give you a single expression on VBA that ArcMaps uses to create labels. In case of single field it would be just '[SingleField]'. So that's it, you only need to parse the real name of the field and check if it exists in attribute table with `arcpy.ListFields`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a little snippet of code that might get you started with looping through using arcpy. This is very basic and not tested but could be easily modified to suit your needs, I think.

```
layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(yourMXD)
labelField = 'SomeFieldName'
for layer in layers:
    fields = [field.name for field in arcpy.ListFields(layer)]
    if labelField not in fields:
        print layer
```

There's also arcpy.mapping.ListBrokenDataSources() which you could add as well depending on your specific needs.

Comment: Thanks, I know how to loop through. The problem I´m looking the answer for is that I don´t know the attribute field for labeling because the window in the Label tab is blank - how do I find out which attribute field was set in the feature class that has been replaced?